# Convert a space separated file (eachy row = vector) to SequenceFile

Tags: hadoop, mahout, sequencefile

I created the large text file (4 GB) as followings.

```
0 1 2 3 2 1
3 6 2 0 6 4
3 0 6 3 0 0
1 6 7 3 9 4
```

Each row describes a vector, and each column denotes each element of the vector. Each element is separated by one space.

Now, I would like to execute K-Means clustering for all the vectors with Apache Mahout, but I received the error `"not a SequenceFile"`.

How can I create the file whose format meets the requirement of mahout?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/creating-vectors-from-text.html